# Add data to Google Sheet using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone explain why this script get a error message.

My code is:

```
  var wbook = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qqyKJwc1TTOQyJL0iXbKNhRIvhLHoj10QxpGdosKPv8/');
  
  var sheet = wbook.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 
  function doPost(e)
  {
    var action = e.parameter.action;

    if (action == 'addUser')
     {
      return addUser(e);
     }
  }

  function addUser(e) {
    var user = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
    sheet.appendRow([user.name]);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(("Success"))
 
 }
```

[image]

When I call this script using API Testing Tool I get this error message.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendRow') (line 6, file "Code")

Comment: There's no sheet with the name "Sheet1" in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Try it without nesting the function declarations.

Comment: How i try this ?

Comment: Your spreadsheet is public, I would not recommand to keep it like this. But there is a `Sheet1` sheet, so I guess you only have to deplace your first two lines inside doPost as @Cooper said